# JAVA - How to add COLORBAR to image in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

I have to plot a magnitude spectrum with color bar on the right side of result image, such as the following example (generated by my Python prototype script):

[image: The desired result]

However, I am having trouble porting this code to Java. So far I have managed to plot the magnitude spectrum:

[image: In Java i can do this]

Unfortunately, I am having trouble plotting the color bar. Could you, please, propose some ideas on how to implement it?

Comment: what do you have so far? please show us what you have tried.

Comment: click on the links above to my result image

Comment: You can't do this directly with opencv... you need gui facilities not provided by opencv

Comment: @Miki Unless this needs some interactivity, drawing into a `Mat` would be enough. Few lines, some text, copy-to of a pre-calculated `Mat` with the gradient. Wouldn't take much work to implement.

Comment: @dan it's not as easy as it seems... and you can't do this directly with opencv, but you need to code the colorbar yourself... it's not as straightforward as in matlab or python

Comment: @Miki Ya, I agree it's not as straightforward as Matlab or Python. But it's not that difficult a problem in scope of things we usually apply OpenCV on. | The colormap looks like JET. Make 256 row, 1 column `Mat` filled with 0-255. `applyColorMap` and `resize` with say linear interpolation. That should make a good enough colour bar. Then some fairly basic math to position and draw the ticks and text. But I guess my perspective may be a bit skewed regarding the difficulty. Wouldn't mind writing it up in C++, but I haven't touched Java since school.

Comment: @DanMašek I tried your idea, it's pretty cool. But i don't know how to count values of the color's bar. Sometime are the values between <0,12> sometime <0,20>. Do you have some idea ?

Comment: My guess would be that this is determined from the input "magnitude spectrum" `Mat`. Could you please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42820279/edit) and paste your Python prototype script, and whatever you currently have in Java? (Especially the Python bit.)

Comment: see [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/28899/correct-hsv-inrange-values-for-red-objects/#28901) may be it will be helpful